# Can I run bulk update for URL aliases at command line?

Tags: 7, path-aliases

I have over 30,000 nodes, and bulk update is painfully slow. Is there another way to run this?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use Drush for the bulk update, see [this article](http://drupal.org/node/236304).

Comment: There are [specific Drush commands](http://drupal.org/node/867578) in the works for this.

Comment: Your linked article works for Drupal 6 only. On 7 it returns `Fatal error: Call to undefined function _pathauto_include() in /Users/tfejfar/.composer/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/core.drush.inc(1100) : eval()'d code on line 1`

Answer (score 1):

I would look at the code of the path_alias module and then optimize that. It's probably slow because it runs some checks before updating each node. If you are sure about your naming structure you might be able to an optimized query.